# Is there a way to convert a function to expressions in Julia?

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

I am trying to create a macro which is capable of (probably recursively) turn a function into expressions so as to reach the operations applied within that function.

As a visualization:

```
function sampleFunc(x)
     println(x)
     y = 2x
     return 2y* x
end

@macroIcannotImplement sampleFunc(x)
```

Desired Output:

```
quote
     println(x)
     y = 2x
     return 2y* x    
end
```

Does Julia support such an extraction or should I start searching for other ways?

Comment: What do you plan to then do with this? It's not something that's generally going to take you to good places. You might be interested in some of the ideas I was playing with in Arborist.jl though. https://github.com/oxinabox/Arborist.jl but they don't go towards practical code.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use [CodeTracking](https://github.com/timholy/CodeTracking.jl):

```
julia> using Revise, CodeTracking

julia> function sampleFunc(x)
            println(x)
            y = 2x
            return 2y* x
       end
sampleFunc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_expr sampleFunc(3)
:(function sampleFunc(x)
      #= REPL[2]:1 =#
      #= REPL[2]:2 =#
      println(x)
      #= REPL[2]:3 =#
      y = 2x
      #= REPL[2]:4 =#
      return (2y) * x
  end)
```